# How to set aes cfb feedback segment size in nodejs crypto lib?

Tags: node.js, encryption

I have this python 2.7 code with AES from Crypto.Cipher:

```
self.cipher_down = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CFB, self.iv, segment_size=128)
```

How can I set cfb segment size (also known as feedback size) in node.js crypto lib?
Here is my node.js snippet:

```
let cph = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cfb', this.key, this.iv);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `crypto` module of NodeJS is based on OpenSSL and therefore uses the same names, see [here](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto). Whether a mode is supported in NodeJS depends therefore also on OpenSSL, see [here](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createcipheriv_algorithm_key_iv_options).

OpenSSL and thus NodeJS append the number of bits `n` encrypted per encryption step to the name, i.e. `...-cfbn` (e.g. `aes-128-cfb8`). `...-cfb8` therefore corresponds to `segment_size = 8`, with the exception of `n = 128` or `segment_size = 128`, which is simply referred to as `...-cfb`.

Since in Python `n` must be a multiple of 8 (at least for PyCryptodome) there is no counterpart to `...-cfb1`.

There is a bug in the legacy PyCrypto library in the context of CFB mode that requires the plaintext to have a length that is an integer multiple of the segment length. Otherwise the following error occurs: *Input strings must be a multiple of the segment size 16 in length.*